# Bolt 4 Add Records Programmatically via Cron

Tags: bolt-cms

Want to add content to **bolt 4 programmatically** however can only really see 1 example for Bolt 3.

Would like this to run via **cron** in long run however this functionality looks on the backburner for Bolt 4 too but sure I can botch a way to run.

Within **Bolt 3** the below was suggested:

```
$values = file('myfile.csv');

// now create an associative array to use below

$record = $this->app['storage']->getEmptyContent($contenttypeslug);
$record->setValues($values);

$id = $this->app['storage']->saveContent($record);
```

This however does not seem to work as i'm guessing a lot has changed in this update. I intend to get my data via api and then run similar to above if anyone in the know can suggest how to go about this?

I have started by looking at using `Bolt\Repository\ContentRepository;` and `Bolt\Controller\Backend\ContentEditController` by trying to pick apart similar functionality here:

https://github.com/bobdenotter/conimex/blob/master/src/Import.php

However this seems overly complicated for me to quite pick apart and just want a simpler example maybe with image / image galleries.

So far I have started with a command line function then can use system cron to run it at desired frequency. The below code is not working for many reasons firstly `getFieldToUpdate` seems to throw a private function error and can't seem to get passed that.

```
public function import(): void
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    /** @var Content $content */
    $slug = 'test-property';

    $contentTypeSlug = 'properties';
    $contentType = $this->config->getContentType($contentTypeSlug);
    $content = $this->contentRepository->findOneBySlug($slug, $contentType);

    if (! $content) {
        $content = new Content($contentType);
        $content->setStatus('published');
        $content->setAuthor($user);
    }
    $content->setFieldValue("bedrooms", 2);
    //$field = $this->contentEditController->getFieldToUpdate($content, 'bedrooms');
    //$this->contentEditController->updateField($field, $item, null);
    //$content->setFieldValue($key, $item);
    
    $this->em->persist($content);
    $this->em->flush();
    
}

private function getUser()
{
    $user = null;

    // Fall back to the first user we can find. ‍
    if (! $user) {
        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy([]);
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a working example here:

https://github.com/bobdenotter/phpnews_2019/blob/master/src/RssFetcherExtension.php#L93-L191

Comment: Thanks, should of looked at that one, looks like an easier example to work from.

Comment: Only bit im not quite getting in that is adding an image from URL? Like generating this {"media":11,"filename":"entity\/year\/month\/image.jpg","alt":"","0":""} and having image uploaded. Is that a simple way of doing that?

Comment: created another question if you know of any other examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67883398/populate-image-image-list-fields-with-bolt-cms-programatically