# Populate Image & Image List Fields with Bolt CMS Programatically

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, bolt-cms

I am attempting to create entries programaticaly in Bolt 4. I have managed to create basic text entries fine which covers the majority of fields I need to fill in however unsure how to go about image and image list types.

```
$content->setFieldValue('name', 'Test Name');
```

Works fine for most fields as stated but images field types looks like below in database and am unsure what the "Bolt / Symfony / Doctrine" way of generating below is:

```
{"media":11,"filename":"entity\/year\/month\/image.jpg","alt":"","0":""}
```

Which looks like some JSON formatted to contain a media ID, file path and an alt attribute. I'm guessing image lists are similar but with multiple of above but hoping there is a function I can use to generate this output as unsure how I would grab media ID etc.

Am assuming I may need to upload a file temporarily from  an external URL and provide this to some function however cannot find any examples. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure on this but will answer anyway as it works and may help someone else, but would be good to clear some of the bits up.

**Example of an Image:**

```
//not sure what goes in media here but blank seemed to not work here but a 7 did as looked at example in database however worried this is wrong and should be an Id
$image = array('media' => '7', 'filename' => $filename, 'alt' => $image['Alt'], '0' => '');

$imageJSON = json_encode($image);
$content->setFieldValue('image', $image);
```

**Example of an Image List:**

```
$images = array();

foreach ($images as $image) {
     $ImageId = $image['id'];
     //images may be already on system but I had to download them here 
     if ($fileName = $this->downloadImage($propertyFile->{'url'}->__toString(), $ImageId)) {
         //not sure what goes in media here but seemed to work blank for imagelist type and unsure what the 0 is on the end either
         $image[] = array('media' => '', 'filename' => $filename, 'alt' => $image['Alt'], '0' => '');  }
}

$imageJSON = json_encode($image);
$content->setFieldValue('gallery', $image);
```